# Embedded Ruby in database.yml not being parsed in RubyMine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rubymine

I am using RubyMine 7.0.4 to build a Rails(4.2.0) application with Postgres as my database. I am using environment variables to hold my local configuration (DB_USERNAME and DB_PASSWORD), but RubyMine can't parse the embedded ruby in the database.yml file.

database.yml excerpt:

```
...
development:
  <<: *default
  database: my_app_development
  username: <%= ENV['DB_USERNAME'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['DB_PASSWORD'] %>
...
```

[image: RubyMine Error Popup]

I even tried switching it to the actual credentials within the <%= %> tags, but same issue:

```
...
development:
  <<: *default
  database: my_app_development
  username: <%= 'my_app' %>
  password: <%= 'password' %>
...
```

This seems to be a RubyMine issue, since everything is executing perfectly from the command line/the application works fine. However, I like having my database integrated with the IDE, so it'd be great if I could get this working again.

Is there anything that I can do to execute the embedded ruby instead of treating it as a string?

Comment: Try to rename your database.yml to database.yml.erb. As I remember files are read from right to left: That means, that first your <%= %> are read and put into 'normal' yaml.

Comment: That was a good idea. I just tried renaming it, but no change–my app still understands erb in yaml, but RubyMine does not.

Answer (score 3):

This is a bug within RubyMine that is unfortunately still not yet fixed.

For further info please refer to https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-9223

The only fix I managed to come up with so far, is to add the database.yml to your .gitignore file (if you're pushing your project to a remote repo) and store the username and password as plain text.

The second approach could be just inputting your db_password and db_username as plain texts for development and test databases, and using ENV["DB_USERNAME"] and ENV["DB_PASSWORD"] for the production DB only.